# LEFT JOIN with db_select()

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to do a left join but it isn't working.

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE profile
- uid
- pid

TABLE field_data_field_naam
- entity_id
- field_naam_value
```

I want to select the `field_naam_value` where `uid` is equal to .. and `pid` equal to `entity_id`. My normal query looks like this:

```
SELECT fdfm.field_naam_value, pf.uid
FROM field_data_field_naam fdfm
LEFT JOIN profile pf
ON fdfm.entity_id=pf.pid
WHERE pf.uid = 4
```

When I execute this on my database it works. Then I have this:

```
$naam = db_select('field_data_field_naam', 'fdfm')
     ->fields('fdfm', array('field_naam_value'));
$naam->leftJoin('profile', 'pf', 'fdfm.entity_id = pf.pid');
$naam->condition('uid', 4)
     ->execute();
```

And when I do the following:

```
foreach ($naam as $record) {
    die;
}
```

nothing happens... (he doesn't kill the app). Also tried to add `->fetchAll()` but no success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the below code for fetching values. It will give you `field_naam_value` field data.

```
$naam = db_select('profile', 'pf');
$naam->join('field_data_field_naam', 'fd', 'pf.pid = fd.entity_id');
$all_names = $naam->fields('fd', ['field_naam_value'])
  ->condition('pf.uid', 4, '=')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();
foreach ($all_names as $record) {
  die;
}
```