# How to join the `field_data_field_*` tables with `node` table using SQL?

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I apologize if I ask for something obvious, but I am asking because I could not find a simple answer anywhere.

I know how to work with these tables in the PHP Drupal code, which built-in functions to use, etc., but for some reasons, I have to write a literal SQL query to the Drupal database.

That's why I'm asking what condition I need to use in the SQL query to connect the `field_data_field_abc` table with the `node` table?

If the data in the `field_data_field_abc` table contains the `entity_type` column with the value "*node*", can I do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_abc abc ON n.nid = abc.entity_id
WHERE abc.entity_type = 'node'
```

Comment: In fact, I only need to confirm whether I think well or wrong if I'm wrong, I'd like to ask you how to write some example query?

Comment: Take a look at this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121960/left-join-with-db-select and this https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2012-02-14/db_selectleft-join-vs-db_query

Comment: OK, thank you @berramou for these links. The content of these pages indirectly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right :)

In general, for each table from `field_data_field_*` family, if its `entity_type` is equal to  the "*node*" value, then it can be associated with the `n.nid` from the `node` table and if the `entity_type` is equal to the "*user*" then the `entity_id` value is associated with the `uid` value from the `users` table.

I hope it will help somebody.